# Procedure checking set up parameters (PL/SQL, ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql, package, oracle12c

In the package I have couple of procedure that set global variables, example below:

```
...
 PROCEDURE setA (pp IN VARCHAR2)
    IS BEGIN global_vName := pp; END;

 PROCEDURE setB (qq IN VARCHAR2)
    IS BEGIN global_vColor := qq; END;

 FUNCTION getA RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS BEGIN RETURN global_vName; END;

 FUNCTION getB RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS BEGIN RETURN global_vColor; END;
...
```

Now in the PL/SQL block I'm doing test if they are working correclty:

```
Begin
 mypack.setA('NameA');
 mypack.setB('ColorB');
End;
```

How to write a procedure that will check if `global_vName` and `global_vColor` are set up?

If they are null procedure should return exception. Please help.

Comment: At which moment you need to check? Which type of exception (standard/user defined) you need to raise?

Comment: after end -> if someone use package and let say forget to set-up one variable then should be some message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
FUNCTION getA RETURN VARCHAR2 IS 
BEGIN 
   IF global_vName IS NULL THEN
      RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
   END IF;
   RETURN global_vName; 
END;
```

Comment: can I somehow execute this function couple of time to check all variables?

Comment: What do you like to achieve? Your entire design looks a bit strange. Note, in general PL/SQL means "structured programming", not "object-oriented programming". I don't think it is a good idea to impose OOP to PL/SQL.

Comment: if you run one of my procedure from pack, and it required to setA or setB, the procedure should return that something SET is missing, raise a exception

Comment: This is simple exception handling - what is your problem?

Comment: I did not know if need to do simple if statement or are there other rules to do that

Comment: I used your solution and I added EXCEPTION when NO_DATA_FOUND....as I need to check a few param, I convert it into procedure

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to execute some code after the `end` statement - you should write it explicitly if you need additional check. As I understand, you want be sure that global variables are always initialized, so you can use the package initialization:

```
create or replace package body mypack as 

 PROCEDURE setA (pp IN VARCHAR2)
    IS BEGIN global_vName := pp; END;

 PROCEDURE setB (qq IN VARCHAR2)
    IS BEGIN global_vColor := qq; END;

 FUNCTION getA RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS BEGIN RETURN global_vName; END;

 FUNCTION getB RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS BEGIN RETURN global_vColor; END;

< here are your other functions and procedures >

begin
  -- here is an initialization section
  setA('NameA');
  setB('ColorB');
end mypack;
```

The initialization section will be executed automatically by Oracle before the first user's call to package (function, procedure, cursor, variable, etc.). So you can be sure that your variables are always initialized.

Comment: all SET are done outside package, example: I will setA, setB ...then run other procedure, where if you did not setA or setB it will not run, but should raise a exception like missing setA

Comment: @4est Take the logic to define initial values, and implement it in the initialization section.